# Python program being blocked by windows defender

Tags: python, webserver, pyinstaller, windows-defender

Hi i have been trying to make a program for my school that can get questions form a web server and use TTS to say them on a speaker. When i try to upload the version that has been ran through Pyinstaller to any thing it gets blocked for being a trojan is their any way to get around this other than having the recipient allow it through allowing it on windows defender. Hear is the Source code it is the one in the "Speaker" folder: https://github.com/foxface918/School-tts

Comment: Normally you can set an exception for every finding. Just on the details... On the other hand, if an anti-virus program throws a detection, you should concern about security

Comment: I think it because i am making a get request to my web server but i don't know how to make that more secure its already using https.

Comment: Do not use the [windows] tag for this. Read the usage guidance for it - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/info